# passing the address of array element NOT working in - C -- the way I did

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-address

My swap function and the way I am passing the address of array element to swap is not causing any effect I also tried passing it like `swap(&arr[2],&arr[3])` but no luck

```
void swap(char *a,char *b)
{
    int t=*b;
    b=a;
    a=t;
}

void main()
{
    char *arr=(char[]){'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
    int n=strlen(arr);
    swap((arr+2),(arr+3));
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        printf("%c \n",*(arr+i));
    }
}
```

Comment: `b=a` reassigns the *pointers*. And `a=t` is not correct either.

Comment: The passing is fine. It's the swap-function which is wrong.

Comment: The answer and the comment on it practically only gave you working code. Is that enough? Or do you need to understand the problem and clarify your basic misunderstanding of pointer use? Without that you probably end up with similar problems soon again.

Comment: `arr` is NOT a C-string, it is not nul-terminated. You invoke *Undefined Behavior* with `strlen(arr)`. All bets are off after that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `b=a reassigns the pointers` so does this mean address of a is in b. And is `a=t` means I am assigning variable to local pointer. is this correct understanding?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I did not see the code of strlen. So does this mean I can only create array with specific size but i.e. cant use strlen to find i.e  the length of entire tcp packet that to receive in payload. How in web servers work is done to check for sockets `recvfrom` function buffer size. Someone in development of kernel teams or sockets api developers must need to give the some means of getting size of buffer of incomming packets somewhere in kernel network stack or sockets api. Or buffer overflow will come into play at some point.? u did not give any solution to help fix this. Can u add?

Comment: All of the functions in `string.h` beginning `str...` require a nul-terminated string as their argument. That's how they know when they have reached the end of the input string. (also why you can iterate over a **string** by simply using `for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++)`, but that invokes *Undefined Behavior* with a plain old array). When you provide a plain old character array without a `'\0'` character marking the end, `strlen()` gets to `'f'` and then keeps on reading beyond the end of your array looking for a 0-byte. What it returns after that is simply Undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass things to functions in C, the argument is pushed to the stack (or stored in registers, either way, you only have a local copy of that variable), not a reference to that argument. So when you pass pointers and assign them a different value, that assignment is only valid for the scope of that function.
so in

```
void swap(char *a,char *b)
{
    int t=*b;
    b=a;
    a=t;
}
```

You are assigning the swap functions local copy of the pointer b to the local copy of a. So when this function returns, the local copies are lost. So you must assign a value at the location the pointer.  Also, the next line,

```
a=t;
```

You are assigning a pointer to a value, a big no no in C.
So, your swap function should look like this

```
void swap(char *a,char *b)
{
    char t=*b;
    *b=*a;
    *a=t;
}
```

Comment: _"the argument is pushed to the stack"_:  that may be true or not. Arguments can be passed via registers too, and there may not even be a stack (although in almost all implementations there is a stack). Otherwise the answer is correct.

Comment: @Jabberwocky so when arguments are passed via registers.so does in that case there is real address instead of local copies of arguments? so my way will be correct in that case?

Comment: @Jabberwocky ok got the answer

Comment: @user786 no, that fact that arguments are passed via the stack, via registers or via some other way has absolutely no influence on the behaviour of your code, assuming that this code is proper C code.